# new to android not sure what import info.androidhive.imageslider.R; means

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been working through [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/) and came across this code:

```
import info.androidhive.imageslider.R;
```

This is important because when i copy these files from this tutorial into a new project - it gives me an error on this line of code.

can you give me a detailed explanation on what it means?

Comment: you need import R from your package like `import com.example.tutorial.R;` Replace this `info.androidhive.imageslider` with your package name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the import of your resource library. Resource means where your app store its drawable, layout etc. In most cases, it is under the packages name like:
if your package name is: **info.androidhive.imageslider**
then, your resource package name will be **info.androidhive.imageslider.R**

When you open a new android project, your must notice that there is a **gen folder** where there is a **R.java** file. This import actually import that file to the class where you may use some resource.

As you copied the code from other places, **I think you have changed your project package name and so for that, now the app can't match it with current package for R file. Please, check it and change it according to it.**

Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You got this explained in the tutorial (btw: it's good to read tutorial, not just copy files from it):

> I kept my package name as info.androidhive.imageslider

You must have proper `import` here. If you are using Eclipse, best solution would be to press `CTRL`+`Shift`+`o`.

Comment: i can not make my package name info.androidhive.imageslider because this must be included into another project